# Access datalake from Azure datafactory V2 using on demand HD Insight cluster

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I am trying to execute spark job from on demand HD Insight cluster using Azure datafactory.

Documentation indicates clearly that ADF(v2) does not support datalake linked service for on demand HD insight cluster and one have to copy data onto blob from copy activity and than execute the job. BUT this work around seems to be a hugely resource expensive in case of a billion files on a datalake. Is there any efficient way to access datalake files either from python script that execute spark jobs or any other way to directly access the files.

P.S Is there a possiblity of doing similar thing from v1, if yes then how? "Create on-demand Hadoop clusters in HDInsight using Azure Data Factory" describe on demand hadoop cluster that access blob storage but I want on demand spark cluster that access datalake.

P.P.s Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, we don't have support for ADLS data store with HDI Spark cluster in ADF v2. We plan to add that in the coming months. Till then, you will have to contiue using the workaround as you mentioned in your post above. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

The Blob storage is used for the scripts and config files that the On Demand cluster will use. In the scripts you write and store in the attached Blob storage they can write from ADLS to SQLDB for example.