# Create a Data Pipeline in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

I've a class which make some extract, transform an load to a dataset located in a different JSON files.

This process work Ok. But, I've the necessity to process manually every month. I submitt an spark application in intelliJ (and submit an Scalla Singleton Object with the transformation)

So, I'm trying to automate this process. But, I didn't find documentation or a tutorial to known what is the best service to accomplish this objective.

The processs Should:

1. Create a HDInsight Spark Cluster
2. Run The process (An Scala Class)
3. Delete the HDInsight Spark Cluster created before

I've searched but the links I find (looking for "Create on demand HD insight spark cluster") are the following:

- [Access datalake from Azure datafactory V2 using on demand HD Insight
  cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165947/access-datalake-from-azure-datafactory-v2-using-on-demand-hd-insight-cluster)
- [How to create Azure on demand HD insight Spark cluster    using Data
  Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545182/how-to-create-azure-on-demand-hd-insight-spark-cluster-using-data-factory)

Other options I've searched:

- [Host and run your PowerShell scripts in Azure](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dominiquevives/2018/07/02/host-and-run-your-powershell-scripts-in-azure/)
- Azure Logic Apps
- Azure Automation

Thanks!

Comment: So, which tutorial have you tried now?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the process which you want to

1. Create a HDInsight Spark Cluster

Using power shell it should be easy to create HDInsight cluster, here is a sample code:

```
### Create a Spark 2.3 cluster in Azure HDInsight

# Default cluster size (# of worker nodes), version, and type
$clusterSizeInNodes = "1"
$clusterVersion = "3.6"
$clusterType = "Spark"

# Create the resource group
$resourceGroupName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the resource group name"
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the Azure region to create resources in, such as 'Central US'"
$defaultStorageAccountName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the default storage account name"

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $resourceGroupName -Location $location

# Create an Azure storage account and container
# Note: Storage account kind BlobStorage can only be used as secondary storage for HDInsight clusters.
New-AzStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $defaultStorageAccountName `
    -Location $location `
    -SkuName Standard_LRS `
    -Kind StorageV2 `
    -EnableHttpsTrafficOnly 1

$defaultStorageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey `
                                -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
                                -Name $defaultStorageAccountName)[0].Value

$defaultStorageContext = New-AzStorageContext `
                                -StorageAccountName $defaultStorageAccountName `
                                -StorageAccountKey $defaultStorageAccountKey

# Create a Spark 2.3 cluster
$clusterName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the HDInsight cluster"

# Cluster login is used to secure HTTPS services hosted on the cluster
$httpCredential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter Cluster login credentials" -UserName "admin"

# SSH user is used to remotely connect to the cluster using SSH clients
$sshCredentials = Get-Credential -Message "Enter SSH user credentials" -UserName "sshuser"

# Set the storage container name to the cluster name
$defaultBlobContainerName = $clusterName

# Create a blob container. This holds the default data store for the cluster.
New-AzStorageContainer `
    -Name $clusterName `
    -Context $defaultStorageContext

$sparkConfig = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$sparkConfig.Add("spark", "2.3")

# Create the HDInsight cluster
New-AzHDInsightCluster `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ClusterName $clusterName `
    -Location $location `
    -ClusterSizeInNodes $clusterSizeInNodes `
    -ClusterType $clusterType `
    -OSType "Linux" `
    -Version $clusterVersion `
    -ComponentVersion $sparkConfig `
    -HttpCredential $httpCredential `
    -DefaultStorageAccountName "$defaultStorageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net" `
    -DefaultStorageAccountKey $defaultStorageAccountKey `
    -DefaultStorageContainer $clusterName `
    -SshCredential $sshCredentials

Get-AzHDInsightCluster `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ClusterName $clusterName
```

2. Run The process (An Scala Class)

You can refer this link to submit an application job remotely to the Spark cluster:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-create-standalone-application#run-the-application-on-the-apache-spark-cluster

3. Delete the HDInsight Spark Cluster created before

Cleaning up the cluster , you can achieve it using powershell, here is a sample code for the same;

```
# Removes the specified HDInsight cluster from the current subscription.
Remove-AzHDInsightCluster `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -ClusterName $clusterName

# Removes the specified storage container.
Remove-AzStorageContainer `
    -Name $clusterName `
    -Context $defaultStorageContext

# Removes a Storage account from Azure.
Remove-AzStorageAccount `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Name $defaultStorageAccountName

# Removes a resource group.
Remove-AzResourceGroup `
    -Name $resourceGroupName
```

Additional reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-jupyter-spark-sql-use-powershell

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-build-your-first-pipeline-using-powershell.md

Hope it helps.